# Please help me use the selection description to write a program that displays the corresponding four seasons according to the month entered by the use

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Please use the selection description to write a program that displays the corresponding four seasons according to the month entered by the user
input Output:
(one)
Month 11
winter

Comment: What does this have to do with google-bigquery or python-requests?

Comment: Is `0 = January` or `1 = January`?

Comment: (1) is just a number

Comment: month 11(november) are the point @Samathingamajig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert the 12 for December to a 0, perform a floored division by 3 to get a number in the interval [0, 3], then use that number as an index for the different seasons.

You can replace "Autumn" with "Fall" depending on your dialect.

```py
def season(month: int = 1):
  return ["Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Autumn"][month % 12 // 3]
```

Example:

```py
for i in range(1, 13):
  print(i, season(i))

# Outputs
1 Winter
2 Winter
3 Spring
4 Spring
5 Spring
6 Summer
7 Summer
8 Summer
9 Autumn
10 Autumn
11 Autumn
12 Winter
```